# Tag search results are not cleared on mobile web

Tags: bug, tags, mobile-web, tag-search

When I search for a specific term in the tag page in the full site, for example when I type `j` in the [Coffee beta tag search page](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/tags), no results end up if there is no match. Perfectly fine.

> [image: fine]

However, if I search using the mobile site, the existing tags are not being cleared when there is no match, hence I get all the tags. This is very confusing.

> [image: not fine]

Please clear any existing results in the tag search if there is no match in the mobile theme.

Comment: It doesn't return all the tags,  it just doesn't update when there's no tags to match. I.e., type "esp" and then add some random letters.

Comment: Okay, more or less the same end result ;)

Comment: Yup, that's true.

Comment: @Paweł the bug is too complex?